# Chrome Print Changes Layout

Tags: google-chrome, layout, printing

When I  print a page on my site from Chrome the layout goes wonky.  See what I mean [here](http://slotted.co).  You can see that the top menu, which is a `ul`, goes from horizontal to vertical. Thoughts?

UPDATE: Just to be clear, the problem is not with the print rendering. The act of simply opening the print dialog causes the ***screen*** layout to change.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this problem myself in a similar issue. It appears Chrome has trouble recalculating auto widths after showing a print preview. Not sure about a better fix in this case, but if you hard-code the width of your ul.nav it seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score -2):

You can control the print layout by adding styles for the print media type.

```
@media print
  {
  p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
  }
```

or

```
<link href="print-styles.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Further Reading**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: The problem is not controlling the print layout; the print layout is perfect.  The problem is that the screen layout changes by simply opening the print dialog.